# $(y+x^2)y''+y=0$ with power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

I'm trying to solve this ODE using power series:
$$(y+x^2)y''+y=0$$
I tried to solve it, keeping in mind that $x=0$ is a singular point, then substituting $y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$, but I didn't get anything helpful. I've also checked that it isn't equidimensional or scale-invariant.

I have been asked to express the solution as a linear combination of two power series, then compute the radius of convergence. Do I need to solve the ODE anyway?

Comment: Could you show us what you already made ?

Comment: I tried to solve it keeping on mind that $x=0$ is a singular point and substituting $y = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ but I didn't get nothing helpfull.

Comment: i think for this ode we can't get a nice solution

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I corrected it. I also tried it at first but, same problem, I got stuck trying to get a closed form or seeking for a contradiction.

Comment: I also checked if it is an equidimensional equation or a scale-invariant equation.

Comment: A particular solution is : $y=-\frac{3}{2}x^2$ . The most probably there is no closed form for the general solution. If the ODE comes from an academic exercise, either there is a mistake in the ODE, or it is asked to answer to the exercise without need to solve the ODE.

Comment: The problem specifically asks me to express the general solution as a linear combination of two power series and then, compute their convergence radius. Do not I need to solve the ODE for this?

Comment: Just an idea... maybe it does not work, but you could try to solve $y_0\cdot{y_0''}+y_0=0$ and $x^2\cdot{y_1''}+y_1=0$ and, then, express $y$ as their linear combination: $y=y_0+y_1$

Comment: Let $u=y+x^2$ , the ODE becomes $u''=\dfrac{x^2}{u}+1$

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=y+x^2$ ,

Then $u'=y'+2x$

$u''=y''+2$

$\therefore u(u''-2)+u-x^2=0$

$uu''-u-x^2=0$

$u''=\dfrac{x^2}{u}+1$

You can consider as two members Emden-Fowler type nonlinear ODE and follow the method in http://www.sciencepubco.com/index.php/ijamr/article/download/723/628